# Somar colunas de uma matriz por linha e colocar o total em uma nova coluna

Tags: r

Tenho uma matriz 5x5 com valores numéricos, tal como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
 1      2      3      4      5
 1      2      3      4      5
 1      2      3      4      5
 1      2      3      4      5
 1      2      3      4      5
```

Preciso criar uma nova coluna nessa matriz contendo a soma das colunas linha a linha, tal como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   SOMA
 1      2      3      4      5      15
 1      2      3      4      5      15
 1      2      3      4      5      15
 1      2      3      4      5      15
 1      2      3      4      5      15
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Seria importante você apresentar um pouco da estrutura dos dados, mas por alto, dá para tentar ajudar.

# Crie uma coluna nova:

dataframe$NOME_DA_COLUNA <- dataframe[1] + dataframe[2] + dataframe[3] + dataframe[4] + dataframe[5]

Comment: `base$SOMA <- rowSums(base)`. É só isto. Mas essa tabela é mais parecida com um objeto de classe `"data.frame"` com com um objeto de classe `"matrix"`. Se for uma matriz, `base <- cbind(base, SOMA = rowSums(base))`.